# How to return only one value if none of foreach iterations match condition

Tags: php

I have piece of code like this

```
foreach ($item->offers as $offer) {
    foreach ($json as $akey => $article){
        if ($article['A'] == $offer->OfferName){

            echo $article['B'];

            break;

        } else {

            echo $offer->OfferName

        }

    }
                                    
}
```

As you can see I want to loop through offers and see if they exist in json.
If they exist I want to get value B of article but if not I want just to echo offer name.

Unfortunately else statement return all of non matching iterations and I have no idea how to force it to return it only once.

E: I want return some value if none of iterations in second loop is matching given condition.

Maybe someone familiar with PHP know the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Its not clear what you actually want.

Comment: There may be a better way if we could see your data, but a simple way is to set a flag to say you have found what you are after, default to false.  Set to true when found and after the loops if still false then use the default.

Comment: Do you mean you want to exit the second `foreach` from within your else statement? If so, you could try writing `break 2;` at the end of the else statement code block.

Answer (score 0):

Your else statement is defined within a second tier foreach so its normal to get the OfferName every single time - that's the logic you coded.

If I understand you correctly, you want the article value rendered only when each key matches your criteria, and the offer name if there's a key that doesn't match it. If this is the case then you can do this:

```
$match = 0;
$output = '';
foreach ( $item->offers as $offer ) {
    foreach ( $json as $akey => $article){
        if ($article['A'] == $offer->OfferName){

            $output .= $article['B'].PHP_EOL;

            // break; - this is pointless

        } else {

            $match = $offer->OfferName;

        }

    }

}

echo ( $match == 0 ? $output : $match);
```